# Economics Behind the Insulin Shortage?

Tags: supply-and-demand

A lot of my family is concerned about a future insulin shortage and it's reported that this shortage is growing.  When I read articles from Harvard about it, [they imply it's pure greed](http://harvardpolitics.com/united-states/how-insulin-became-unaffordable/):

> There are no generic insulins. Over the past twenty years, prices for the most commonly prescribed “analog” insulins have risen from about $20 per vial to well over \$250 per 10 mL vial, an over 700% increase after accounting for inflation. In contrast, insulin today costs roughly five dollars per vial to produce. With deductibles far outpacing wages, insulin has become unaffordable even for well-off Americans.

If it costs us 5 dollars to produce, why don't we all start insulin companies and sell it for $15, attracting all the business (as well as popularity since we have better prices).  Is greed really the issue, or is there another economic explanation, like the resources involved in insulin-making are in a shortage?  Or the regulation of producers?  Or the possible lawsuits producers face if they make a mistake?

It sounds like anyone could compete against these greedy companies and put them out of business.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing patents.

I recommend reading the paper "[Why Is There No Generic Insulin? Historical Origins
of a Modern Problem](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58011633197aea95712e5e2f/t/596cf3f4e45a7cff8a3d3656/1500312565180/Why+is+there+no+generic+insulin.pdf)" by doctors Greene and Riggs.

> ...high costs of
>   pharmaceutical research and development are
>   often invoked to justify the high price tags of new
>   medications. Although the price point of effective new drugs — from hepatitis cures to new
>   agents for heart failure — may initially be out of
>   reach for many patients, market laws predict
>   that drugs with strong demand should become
>   more accessible after market exclusivity ends
>   and generic competition begins. Since 1984,
>   when the Drug Price Competition and Patent
>   Term Restoration Act was passed, pharmaceutical innovation and access have been balanced on
>   that premise: innovative drugs are rewarded
>   with high prices during their window of patent
>   protection, and generic competition reduces
>   prices thereafter.
>
> [...] incremental innovation has repeatedly precluded the formation of a generic insulin industry in North America when earlier
>   patents expired. The history of insulin hasn’t followed the standard chronology of pharmaceutical innovation, in which patent monopolies predictably give way to generic competition.
>   
>   Viewed in historical perspective, insulin is not
>   a single entity but a family of related products
>   that has evolved through incremental improvements. Subsequent iterations of insulin represented actual innovations, each one being safer,
>   more effective, or more convenient than its predecessor. And yet after generations of incremental
>   innovation, insulin may be no more affordable
>   than it was when the original patent holders
>   sold their stake for $1 to ensure access to this
>   essential medicine. 
>   Pharmaceutical-industry analysts have described a repatenting tactic called evergreening,
>   in which a series of related patents — often on
>   metabolites or optical isomers — extend the life
>   of a product after initial patent expiration.